# Android Studio 1.0.1 shows weird text in many places (found: bug in Darcula theme)

Tags: android, text, intellij-idea

On some places in the IDE I have very strange text:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

I also have IntelliJ on this pc and it doesn't have that problem. Earlier versions of Android Studio didn't have this problem either.

How can I fix this? Do I miss a font or some files?

Here is my Android Studio about tab:

[image: Android Studio]

My Host OS is Windows 8.1

EDIT

If I copy and paste the text into any text editor, I do see the correct text.

EDIT 2

Doesn't work after the new update Android 1.0.2 either

Comment: btw: restart everything doesn't help + it's a clean install

Comment: What are the File Encodings you are using??

Comment: IDE encoding: UTF8 and Autodetect, project encoding "System default"

Comment: Not all text is wierd

Comment: Inside settings search for Lossy Encoding and disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. Obviously it is a bug in Android Studio. The bug is in the theme I have selected (Darcula theme). When I switched it back to "Windows", it was fixed.

Comment: I reported this bug, only had an answer to clarify my report even more but I'm not sure if they are going to fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **File > Settings > Editor > Font** and Change the font to any of the readable ones.

[Font Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW2fa.png)