# Unreadable code in Android Studio projects

Tags: android-studio, ide

I have a problem with Android Studio, the content of each text in the editor is illegible, even line numbers.

Everything happened after a push to a repository. When loading the project in Android Studio.

[![Illegible Text Image][1]][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoJh9.png

- OS: Windows 10.
- Android Studio 3.2.1
- No matter what file or project I open, everything looks the same
- Files looks good in any other editor
- IDE language is fine, only editor gets corrupted
- When copying any text from the editor to the clipboard, the text is pasted well elsewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533679/weird-text-in-android-studio / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418571/android-studio-1-0-1-shows-weird-text-in-many-places-found-bug-in-darcula-them ?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **File > Settings > Editor > Font** and Change the font to any of the readable ones

[Font Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syZih.png)